# Muted Role is not being created

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, roles

I created a `temporary mute` command and my bot checks if the guild has a role called, `Muted`. Therefore, if a user executed the command in the guild where `Muted` role does not exist it creates one for them. However, I run into a problem where the bot creates a role named, `new role` instead of `Muted` [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QStEE.jpg). And if a user executed the command for the second time in the guild it creates a duplicate of the `new role` role; as the `Muted` role is not found [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9GWt.jpg).

```
    let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(m => m.name === "Muted");
    if (!muteRole) {
       try {
          muteRole = await message.guild.roles.create({
             name: "Muted",
             color: "#000000",
             permissions:[]
          });

          message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
             await channel.createOverwrite(muteRole, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                MANAGE_MESSAGES: false,
                READ_MESSAGES: false,
                ADD_REACTIONS: false
             });
          });
       } catch(e) {
       console.log(e.stack);
     }
   }
```

Comment: what discord.js version are you using?

Comment: Discord.js v12.2

Answer (score 1):

As per [the discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create), you have to put `name`, `color` and `permission` inside the `data` property. Here's their example for that method:

```js
// Create a new role with data and a reason
guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Super Cool People',
    color: 'BLUE',
  },
  reason: 'we needed a role for Super Cool People',
})
```

Comment: Thanks I got it working! The first time I tried what's in the docs didn't work for me as I forgot to input the permission.